# Como resolver conflito entre Vue.js e Laravel 5.4 no .blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tenho o seguinte elemento no .blade (com a intenção de interagir com o vue não com o laravel):

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Pra tentar ativar o vue:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    seen: true
  }
})
```

E recebo o seguinte erro do laravel:

> Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message' (this will throw
>   an Error in a future version of PHP) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Game\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Esse erro se dá pela sintaxe do blade `{{ message }}`, bom não estou conseguindo pensar em como combinar o .blade com o vue, aparentemente o laravel oferece um suporte pra isso, porém não consegui descobrir como funciona.

A duvida é:

> Como usar o vue.js num .blade da view de uma aplicação laravel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir do Laravel 5.3+ existe um melhoria no blade (`@verbatim`), pra lidar com casos aonde você irá usar muitas vezes o `@{{minha_var_javascript}}`

```
@verbatim
<div class="container">
    Hello, {{ name }}.
</div>
@endverbatim
```

Assim você pode usar várias variáveis seja Vue.JS/React.JS ou outro framework javascript, sem ficar colocando o `@{{my_var}}` e sim apenas `{{my_var}}`

Link pra documentação da tag blade: [Blade & JavaScript Frameworks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)

Answer (score 3):

Como o blade já usa `{{ }}` para exibir o conteúdo das variáveis, use `@` para escapar as chaves e assim usar o Vue na sua view com blade:

```
<div id="app">
  @{{ message }}
</div>
```